# Laravel + vuejs spa app with role-base authetication || @websanova || @tymon

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, oauth, roles

I made role-based spa app using @websanova and @tymon libraries.

I have a issue with login page:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of null
 at success
```

Login return null exception. variable $auth is null in my opinion. However If I login second time it works. Why it does not work at first time?

```
success: function() {
 const redirectTo = redirect ? redirect.from.name : app.$auth.user().role === 'admin' ? 'admin.dashboard' : 'dashboard';
 app.$router.push({name: redirectTo});
 },
```

2) Second problem with admin role. Admin dashboard does not open when I login as admin. But user dashboard works good. To my opinion there is a problem with 'role'

```
 meta: {
 auth: {roles: 'admin', redirect: {name: 'login'}, forbiddenRedirect: '/403'}
}
```

All the code here: https://medium.com/@ripoche.b/create-a-spa-with-role-based-authentication-with-laravel-and-vue-js-ac4b260b882f

Answer (score 0):

**edit users table and add role column or change vue-auth**

1-edit users table

```
//users table
$table->string('role');
```

2- edit vue-auth config

```
//vue-auth
rolesKey: 'status'
```